# Mongodb $lookup dynamic collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schema where the item type might vary, and is mentioned in `connections.kind`.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  connections: [{
    kind: String,
    item: { type: ObjectId, refPath: 'connections.kind' }
  }]
});

var organizationSchema = new Schema({ name: String });
```

I am trying to do a dynamic lookup so that the item object is populated. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: '$connections.kind',
            localField: 'connections.item',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'items'
        }
    }
])
```

I know I can do it with [`mongoose.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), but want to know if it is possible with $lookup

Comment: You can use populate db.user.find({}).populate({path:"connections.item"})

Comment: `from` will have the name of the collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now, you can't. The `from` field cannot be an expression and must be a string literal. However, there is an open issue which you can track here that appears to be exactly what you need: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497.

Comment: so, what should be a way to provide a collection's name which exists in a different database other than where you're using $Lookup's from clause? The `From`clause needs a str not a ref to collection such as `var readDocs = new Mongo("mongodb://MongoR:<PWD>@<Server_name>:27017").getDB("<dbname>").collection_name`