# Get ObjectId from DBRef inside sub-array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    // .. some fields
    "mySubArray": [
        {
            "field1": "{\"$ref\": \"otherCollection\", \"$id\": \"...\", \"$db\": \"sameDataTable\"}", // string
            // .. some other fields
        }
    ] 
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    // .. some fields
    "mySubArray": []
}
```

I want to do `$lookup` to `otherCollection` but first i need to get ObjectId from from `field1` string from `mySubArray`.

What i tried to do is pick this ObjectId with `$arrayElemAt` with `$map`'s inside `$project`:

```
[
    { 
        "$match" : {
            // my match
        },
        {
            "$project": { 
                "its": {
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": { 
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$mySubArray",
                                "as": "element",
                                "in": {
                                    "field1": {
                                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            {
                                               "$objectToArray": "$element.field1"
                                            },
                                            1
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        "in": "$$this.v"
                    }
                }
            }
        }/*, 
        {
            $lookup: {
                from:"otherCollection", 
                localField:"mySubArray.id",
                foreignField:"_id", 
                as:"mySubArray.myNewField"
            }
        }*/
    ]
```

So it will be looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    // .. some fields
    "mySubArray": [
        {
            "field1": "{\"$ref\": \"otherCollection\", \"$id\": \"...\", \"$db\": \"sameDataTable\"}", // string
            "myNewFiled": {
                //my new object that i get with $lookup 
            }
            // .. some other fields
        }
    ] 
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    // .. some fields
    "mySubArray": []
}
```

But what i get is no other fields than `_id` and `mySubArray` with null inside:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
    "mySubArray" : [
        null
    ]
}
```

Comment: why you saved `field1` as string? it is difficult to convert into object and FYI `$lookup` can not support dynamic collection name from present query and collection, check the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902878/mongodb-lookup-dynamic-collection so you need to set it static.

Comment: Store field1 as a proper document instead of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To
@turivishal
@d-sm

The problem is i am can not control pushing to db, i just need to read data from it.

**Btw, i found the way:**

1. `$unwind` mySubArray
2. `$addFileds` with `$regexFind` to get `$id` from string
3. `$unwind` regex captures (since i fetch one group)
4. `$addFields` for converting regex string result to `ObjectId`
5. `$lookup`
6. `$unwind` lookup results (since it is array even if i lookup for one object)
7. `$group` mySubArray back